# State change causing rerendering of the APP component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added an onChange event to the Editor.js file, it sets the value of the `value` variable using `setValue` that causes rerender of the App component on every change. Values of both `value` and `query` are needed in Editor.js and Sidebar.js. Is there any better way to do this to improve the performance?

App.js Code:

```
import React, { Suspense, useState } from "react";
import "./assets/output.css";
import Footer from "./components/layouts/Footer";
import Navbar from "./components/layouts/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./components/layouts/Sidebar";
import TableSection from "./components/table/TableSection";

const Editor = React.lazy(() => import("./components/editor/Editor"));

const App = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState("select * from customers");

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-layout-desktop grid-rows-layout-desktop bg-gray-600 h-screen">
      <Navbar />
      <Sidebar setQuery={setQuery} setValue={setValue} />
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading..</div>}>
        <Editor setQuery={setQuery} value={value} setValue={setValue} />
      </Suspense>
      {query ? <TableSection query={query} /> : null}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Remove `lazy load` first and **try again**

Comment: Let me try, when I set 4-5 query from the sidebar continuously, it kind of get freeze.

Comment: I removed that but still it get kind of freeze after setting 5-6 from the sidebar. Is their any better to manage state.

Comment: Which editor are you using in you app?\

Comment: You have defined a state in your App component. When you change any of them, all its internal components are `re-rendered`. You can use the `memo`

Comment: I am using memo on the sidebar component so, it's preventing the sidebar component from rendering but Is there any better way to manage the state?

Comment: @decpk I am using react-ace editor. It just slow down the react app after setting some queries from the side bar. I just want to know how to prevent it from being slow?

Comment: Would you mind if you can create a sandbox, then it would be easy to understand what exactly is the problem here. You can use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: I think I can't share a whole code. Sorry for that

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Is it ok to define shared state in App component like I did?